# What is the logic behind this function and its output? - Queue

Tags: multithreading, queue

```
q=  queue.Queue()
for i in [3,2,1]:
  def f():
    time.sleep(i)
    print(i)
    q.put(i)

  threading.Thread(target=f).start()

print(q.get())
```

For this piece of code, it returns 1.  The reason for this is because the queue is FIFO and "1" is put first as it slept the least time.

extended question,
If I continue to run q.get() twice, it still outputs the same value "1" rather than "2" and "3". Can anyone tell me why that is? Is there anything to do with threading?

Another extended question,
When the code finishes running completely, but there are still threads that haven't finished, will they get shut down immediately as the whole program finishes?

```
q.get()
#this gives me 1, but I suppose it should give me 2
q.get()
#this gives me 1, but I suppose it should give me 3
```

Update:

It is a Python 3 code.

Comment: Add the programming language used in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the language is Python3.

The second and third calls to `q.get()` return `1` because each of the three threads puts a `1` into the queue. There is never a `2` or a `3` in the queue.

I don't fully understand what to expect in this case—I'm not a Python expert—but the function, `f` does not appear to *capture* the value of the loop variable, `i`.  The `i` in the function `f` appears to be the same variable as the `i` in the loop, and the loop leaves `i==1` before any of the three threads wakes up from sleeping. So, in all three threads, `i==1` by the time `q.put(i)` is called.

---

> When the code finishes running completely, but there are still threads that haven't finished, will they get shut down immediately?

No. The process won't exit until all of its threads (including the main thread) have terminated. If you *want* to create a thread that will be automatically, forcibly, *abruptly* terminated when all of the "normal" threads are finished, then you can make that thread a *daemon thread.*

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html, and search for "daemon".